# How not to Allow Cursor go into Input Automatically?

Tags: jquery, html, focus, cursor, placeholder

I have `form` with `input`'s. When it's opened (via jQuery UI: Dialog)... cursor (that think that blinks after your text as you type) automatically jumps into first `input`! It ruins my `placeholder`'s text and I'm looking for way to disallow cursor automatically focus on `input` or set another `input` as default one for focusing-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending code is in the `open()` function of the UI dialog:

```
    $(self.element.find(':tabbable').get().concat(
        uiDialog.find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane :tabbable').get().concat(
            uiDialog.get()))).eq(0).focus();
```

It automatically gives focus to the first tabbable element in the dialog. You can make your input untabbable by setting the property `tabindex="-1"` on the `<input>`.

Hope that helps

Comment: It fixes it, but this isn't the best way to do it. There must be better way. Can't I somehow turn off that "feature" in jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes you can [override](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Developer_Guide) the `open()` function, and include all the relevant code except that part. But when jQuery UI is upgraded you'll have to update your code. Or instead change the tabindex on all elements in your dialog so _something_ can be hit by default (an Okay button or something). Or suggest the feature be optional on the [jQuery bug tracker](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/)